# Display the timeout of review queues in its proper window

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

So I was reviewing some posts in the Triage queue and apparently one of my decisions were wrong. Anyhow before I found out about it, I was wondering why the review queue was empty. Then after I hit the URL directly for one of the queues 
e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage`.

[image]

So it would be way better IMO, if I would be able to see the duration of the timeout and the information itself shown in the 'Review Queues' window in the top right. At least adding a link which would tell you some more information about your current status.

Especially for newcomers like I was might be wondering why they can't see any queues.

Currently that's all I can see for the 'Review Queues':

[image]